# Unable to create a search response object - How do we mock search responses in Nest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, elasticsearch, moq, nest

I am trying to write some unit tests around some code that hits Elasticsearch through Nest, specifically with the `.Search()` call.  I'm trying to set up Moq to return an empty search response when `.Search()` is called like so:

```
var emptyResponse = new Nest.SearchResponse<MyDoc>()
{
    Documents = new List<MyDoc>() // illegal
};

esClient.Setup(x => x.Search<MyDoc>(It.IsAny <Func<SearchDescriptor<MyDoc>, SearchDescriptor<MyDoc>>>())).Returns(emptyResponse);
```

Unfortunately, I can't do this since `Documents` is readonly on `SearchResponse`.  What is the suggested approach for writing unit tests around search calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to mock `SearchResponse` as well. 
Here you have example:

```
var clientMoq = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
var searchResponseMock = new Mock<ISearchResponse<MyDoc>>();
searchResponseMock.Setup(x => x.Documents).Returns(new List<MyDoc> {new MyDoc {Id = 1}});

clientMoq.Setup(x => x.Search<MyDoc>(It.IsAny<Func<SearchDescriptor<MyDoc>, SearchDescriptor<MyDoc>>>()))
    .Returns(searchResponseMock.Object);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to do it with new ES client? There is no interface/abstract class for `SearchResponse` .

Comment: @user18154574 from what I see api of the search method didn't change much and search method still returns ISearchResponse `ISearchResponse<TDocument> Search<TDocument>()`